# Console RPG in DEV C++ / Map

Tags: c++, c++11

Im trying to make a Dev C++ RPG game. Im stuck at the map, its a twodimesnional array with the dimensions measured with how many chars can fit before "breaking" a line. The map prints out just fine, but i want to make the player move with the arrow keys.
Heres what ive got so far (doesnt work):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77

void MapPrint(int StartX, int StartY){
    int Map[12][80]={0};
    Map[StartX][StartY]=1;
    for (int x=0; x<12; x++) 
    { 
        for (int y=0; y<80; y++) 
        { 
            if(Map[x][y]==0){
                std::cout<<"=";
            }
            if (y==80){
                std::cout<<"\n";
                continue;
            }
            if (Map[x][y]==1){
                std::cout<<"#";
                continue;
            }
        }   
    }
}
int main(){
    int Map[12][80]={0};
    int StartX,StartY;
    Map[StartX][StartY]=1;
    int c = 0;
    StartX=6;
    StartY=40;
    MapPrint(StartX,StartY);
    while(1)
    {

        c=0;

        switch((c=getch())) {
        case KEY_UP:
            system("CLS");
            Map[StartX][StartY]=0;
            Map[StartX][StartY+1]=1;
            std::cout<<StartY; //remains of a fix attempt
            MapPrint(StartX,StartY);
        case KEY_DOWN:
            system("CLS");
            Map[StartX][StartY]=0;
            Map[StartX][StartY-1]=1;
            MapPrint(StartX,StartY);
        case KEY_LEFT:
            system("CLS");
            Map[StartX][StartY]=0;
            Map[StartX-1][StartY]=1;
            MapPrint(StartX,StartY);
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            system("CLS");
            Map[StartX][StartY]=0;
            Map[StartX+1][StartY]=1;
            MapPrint(StartX,StartY);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: These lines `int Map[12][80]={0}; int StartX,StartY; Map[StartX][StartY]=1;` in `main` have you access unknown indices in your `Map`, which are potentially out of bounds. The `Map` in your `MapPrint` function is NOT the same `Map` in your `main` function.

Comment: Are you using correct ASCII values of arrow keys?

Comment: @TusharR. What ASCII values would those be?

Comment: @TusharR. Those are not ASCII values. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Just call getch() before switch and try. When you press arrow key, first getch() returns 0 so you can ignore it and next getch() call returns the value which you have used for arrow keys. There is nothing wrong with ASCII values you have set. No change is required there. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modify your code and I made it better. If you have anything to ask, leave a comment below.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define XSIZE 80
#define YSIZE 20

using namespace std;

int c_x=XSIZE/2,c_y=YSIZE/2; //the player will be in the middle of the map
int direction=1;//direction of the player
bool gameOver=false;
int tim=2000,tt;//that's how we set "speed"

void MapPrint(int newX, int newY)
{
    //if the new position of the player if out of the map
    //the game if over
    if(c_x<0 || c_x>XSIZE || c_y<0 ||c_y>YSIZE)
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"GAME OVER!";
        gameOver=true;
        return;
    }

    //printing the map, without using an twodimesnional array

    for (int y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
        {
            if(newX==x && newY==y)cout<<'#';
            else cout<<' ';
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
}

int main()
{

    char c;
    MapPrint(c_x,c_y);

    while(!gameOver)
    {
        //_kbhit() tell us if any key is pressed
        if(_kbhit())
        {

            c=_getch();
            //setting the direction according to key pressed
            if(c=='w')direction=1;
            else if(c=='d')direction=2;
            else if(c=='s')direction=3;
            else if(c=='a')direction=4;

        }

        tt++;
        if(tt>=tim)
        {
            if(direction==1)
            {
                system("CLS");
                c_y--;  // we go up, so y position of the player decrements
                MapPrint(c_x,c_y);
            }
            else if(direction==3)
            {
                system("CLS");
                c_y++;  // we go down, so y position of the player increments
                MapPrint(c_x,c_y);
            }
            else if(direction==4)
            {
                system("CLS");
                c_x--;  // we go to the left, so x position of the player decrements
                MapPrint(c_x,c_y);
            }
            else if(direction==2)
            {
                system("CLS");
                c_x++;  // we go to the right, so x position of the player increments
                MapPrint(c_x,c_y);
            }
            tt=0;
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code works perfectly, but once a direction has been set the player keeps on moving in that direction, i dont know if you intended this or it just has to be like that. Thanks for the help anyway greatly apreciated.

Comment: Yes, that was my intention, if you want to move just once when you press a key, you should delete if(_kbhit()) statement